# Prove that $1+x \le e^x \le 1+x+x^2$ for every $|x| \le 1$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

I get the following inequality formula.

> $$1+x \le e^x \le 1+x+x^2 \le \frac1{1-x}\quad\text{if}\quad |x| \le 1$$

I know $\displaystyle e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$ but I cannot prove the inequalities for $x\lt0$.

Comment: Instantly accepting answers has the inconvenients that one prevents other users to post answers and that wrong answers may become accepted. This is what happened here.

Comment: Aha, after accepting the answer, is it impossible to post mother answers? Oh, from now on i will not accept instantly. Thank you for noticing me this information.

Comment: Not impossible, but not an incentive to do so.

Comment: A standard approach to prove that $e^x\ge1+x$ is to define $g(x)=e^x-1-x$ and to note that $g'(x)=e^x-1$ has the sign of $x$  hence $g$ is decreasing on $x<0$ and increasing on $x>0$. Since $g(0)=0$, $g\ge0$ everywhere, QED. Can you adapt this to show the other inequality?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint: As we know that $\displaystyle e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$

So $e^x \geq 1+x$ as you can delete the part after $1+x$ in the above formula to achieve this part of inequality.

Again we know that $\dfrac{x^2}{2!} \leq x^2$ and so on, hence the right side of the inequality follows.

(for $|x|\leq 1$)

Comment: The right side of the inequality is not true.

Comment: Oh sorry, the condition  is |x| <= 1. sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @Danny_Kim You should edit your question to include that. As stated, the inequality is false.

Comment: -1. Both parts of the proof fail when $x<0$.